# Spring 5 and Hibernate 5 upgrade

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

[image]I am upgrading exiting Spring + Hibernate project from previous version to latest. I made it everything working except the data is not saving to database. There is no error as well. Here is the code. Appreciate your help. Thank you!

ApplicationConfiguration.xml

```
<bean id="providerDao" class="dao.hibernate.ProviderDAOImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="AbcSessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

```
<bean id="ABCSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="AbcDataSource"/>
     <property name="mappingResources">
      <list>
<value>abc/bean/Provider.hbm.xml</value>
</list>
    </property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${abc.showSql}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${abc.dbSchema}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.use_outer_join">true</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

//DataSource

```
<!-- DataSource setup -->
  <bean id="AbcDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName"><value>${abc.jndiName}</value></property>
  </bean> 
<bean id="txManager" 
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="ABCSessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

DAO Calss

```
public class ProviderDAOImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport 
                implements ProviderDAO 
{
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ProviderDAOImpl.class);
    
    public void save(final Provider instance) 
    {
        log.debug("saving Provider instance");            
        getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(instance);
        log.debug("save successful");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried many things as suggested in other posts but still  SAVE is not working. Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: I am able to read the data but only SAVE is not working and no error at all. Still struggling to figure out. Thanks much!

Comment: Where do you call save method, in which context ? Maybe call hibernate  session.flush()

Comment: Did you open a transaction with `@Transactional` or declare your DAO as a `@Repository` ? The XML syntax isn't used much nowadays, annotations are way easier to use.

Comment: Yes, I have been trying all those annotations. @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED,readOnly=false). I did not use repository but I will give it a try.

Comment: MR_Thorynque: This is a working code. I just updated Spring and Hibernate latest jar files. getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(instance); This is used to save. Actually, the entire code is working for retrieving the data but when save, i am getting error.

Comment: Tried adding @Repository as well. Same error. Please see the error screen attached above.

Comment: Hey, if you to try just use .save, posible similiar this.                                              
      @Transactional(readOnly = false)
 public T save(T instance) {
  return (T) getHibernateTemplate().save(instance);
 }

Comment: If I add any of these two lines getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().setFlushMode(FlushMode.AUTO);
         getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().flush(); I am getting org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread. I am going in circles. Appreciate your help.

Comment: What's the full text of the `Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode` exception message?

Comment: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated configuration xml file with latest namespaces and redo all the beans:bean etc. I am not really sure what the issues is but started working with Hibernate Session session.save();.@Transactions etc.